What does &mut is doing in Rust
I’m new to Rust and come from a C++ background.
While playing with some leet questions I found my self with this scenario
struct MyStruct;
pub fn foo(mut my_box: Box<MyStruct>) {
    let mut ptr: &mut MyStruct;
    ptr = &mut my_box;

    let mut ptr2: &mut Box<MyStruct>;
    ptr2 = &mut my_box
}

Imagine there is a box2 for the example. The point is why both of them work, I know that one is a reference to what is inside the box and the other one to the box itself.
Is there some sort of casting, or how can I implement this “operator overloading” for my own structs, please let me know

Deref coercion.
